# Tool to find the number of open postgresql connection in the application

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2, adempiere

Is there any tool to find the number of open postgresql 
connection in the application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267715/whats-the-correct-query-for-getting-the-current-number-of-connections-in-a-postg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> select * from pg_stat_activity;