# Are pg_stat_database and pg_stat_activity really listing the same stuff aka how do I get a list of all backends

Tags: postgresql

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5270806/2171758) to the question [Right query to get the current number of connections in a PostgreSQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267715/right-query-to-get-the-current-number-of-connections-in-a-postgresql-db) the poster implies that

```
SELECT sum(numbackends) FROM pg_stat_database;
```

and

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

give the same results.

However, if I do this on my db the first one says `119` and the second one `30`.

This is the difference as shown by summing `numbackends` and `count`ing:

```
+------+-------------+-------+
|      | numbackends | count |
+------+-------------+-------+
| db1  |           1 |     1 |
| db2  |           1 |     1 |
| db3  |           1 |     1 |
| db4  |           1 |     1 |
| db5  |           2 |     2 |
| db6  |           2 |     2 |
| db7  |          12 |     3 | <--
| db8  |           4 |     4 |
| db9  |           5 |     5 |
| db10 |          78 |    35 | <--
+------+-------------+-------+
```

- Why does this difference exist?
- How can I list each of the `119`-`30`=`89` backends not shown in `pg_stat_activity`?

Comment: the difference is constantly big? it is not a temporary change due to a batch running...

Comment: yep. it's constantly big. why would a batch running cause it?

Comment: I was thinking of a temporary process that open a big number of backend, but not really your case. you can compare `select datname,numbackends from pg_stat_database where numbackends<>0;` and `select datname, count(*) from pg_stat_activity group by datname;` to check the database that has a big difference. Your database is running for a long time ? can it be some backend process that has crashed ? what's happen if you restart ? is the number start to change quickly ?

Comment: good idea. edited the question with the output. from what I can see there are two dbs with diffs. and one with a huge diff. so if I understand you correctly `process != backend != connection`?

Comment: 1 connection create one process on the server ( process = backend). Nothing specific on those 2 DBs?

Comment: nope, not really, more than that they are used more than the other dbs + we recently had a `too many connections`-problem which is the reason I'm trying to debug the conns and hit this

Comment: I don't have a real idea on that, except that could be from some funny stuff on counter because of those error. You will only know if you restart the db and check counter are ok when there is no error.  (I try to replicate too many connections error, but did not got your issue).

Comment: I don't have an answer but both queries are obsolete to find the number of connections due do intra-query parallelism and background workers which did not exist at the time of the linked answer.

Comment: so if I understand correctly backends ≈ the total number of "concurrent processes", while `pg_stat_activity` basically lists one per process. The plot thickens: it looks like you can get a list of all the backends with `SELECT pg_stat_get_activity(NULL)` but it'd be very nice to actually be able to tie these back down to the "parent" system processes.

Comment: I just checked, and background workers for parallel queries are counted in both queries. Also, both queries call `pgstat_fetch_stat_numbackends()` from `backend/postmaster/pgstat.c` to get the total backend count, so I can't imagine what the difference might me. Mysterious.