# max-pool-size for DB connections Keycloak version 11

Tags: postgresql, jboss, keycloak

Trying to investigate an issue regarding a keycloak deployment.
From the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#modify-the-keycloak-datasource) we're seeing that we should alter this property in the stanealone.xml to allow more

However , after altering the standalone xml to this

```
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://${env.DB_ADDR:postgres}/${env.DB_DATABASE:keycloak}${env.JDBC_PARAMS:}</connection-url>
                    <driver>postgresql</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
```

When we allow the JMX connection to the management console I notice this
[max pool size showing 19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pLYB.png)

Is there anything which could be overriding the max-pool-size setting we're using or how would one go about debugging where is derives the max-pool-size if not from the standalone.xml

Comment: This is disturbing... I'm thinking the max-pool-size reported by JMX may grow once more connections are open. 
Could you set the `<initial­-pool­-size>` parameter to a higher value (200 ?) and check if the max-pool-size you see with JMX is higher ?

Comment: Unfortunately adding that doesn't change , when starting up max showing is 20 connections

Comment: Can you tell me which Keycloak version you are using ? I think in older version the <max-pool-size> attribute wasn't nested under <pool>.

Comment: KC version 11.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why exactly you get this issue but I'll try to help to the best of my abilities.

Keycloak 11 uses Widlfy 20, which [offers several options to configure the datasource](https://docs.wildfly.org/20/wildscribe/deployment/subsystem/datasources/data-source/index.html).

Please try to set

- pool-use-strict-min to true
- pool-prefill to true
- min-pool-size to 200
- initial-pool-size to 200

Also, [monitor the number of opened connection on your Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5270806/1722236), and check if they recoup with the JMX report you got.

Finally, if none of these cause a change in your situation I can only suggest to try another ManagedConnectionPool implementation (see mcp attribute)

Comment: Sorry I can't be more useful. Other options are to post an issue on the Keycloak issue tracker (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-community/issues) or ask a new question with the Wildfly tag and maybe some Widlfly expert on StackOverflow will be able to answer.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer because it contains helpful information and resources for further debugging. The issue on our end was actually it was using the standalone-ha.xml rather than the standalone.xml and was never noticed