# The right way to DI NpgsqlConnection postgreSQL with multiple connectionString in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, connection-pooling

I'm struggling to register DI `NpgsqlConnection()` with multiple connection strings in `ASP.NET Core 3.1`, `Dapper v2.0.78` & `Postgres v11`.

I will provide the current state & fix the code below:

### Current State

###### The idea comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218847/how-do-i-handle-database-connections-with-dapper-in-net)

**Step 1**. `Startup.cs --> ConfigureServices()`

```
services.AddTransient<IDbConnectionFactory, DapperDbConnectionFactory>(sp =>
{
  var connectionDict = new Dictionary<DatabaseConnectionName, string>
  {
     { DatabaseConnectionName.Cnn1, "Connectionstring 1"},
     { DatabaseConnectionName.Cnn2, "Connectionstring 2"}
  };
  return new DapperDbConnectionFactory(connectionDict);
});
```

**Step 2**. `DapperDbConnectionFactory` looks like this:

```
public class DapperDbConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly IDictionary<DatabaseConnectionName, string> _connectionDict;

    public DapperDbConnectionFactory(IDictionary<DatabaseConnectionName, string> connectionDict)
    {
        _connectionDict = connectionDict;
    }

    public IDbConnection CreateDbConnection(DatabaseConnectionName connectionName)
    {
        string connectionString = null;

        if (_connectionDict.TryGetValue(connectionName, out connectionString))
        {
            return new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString); // <--- I think the issue comes from here
        }

        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}
```

**Step 3**: the way I use this code:

```
public ConstructorMedthod(IDbConnectionFactory _connFactory)
{
   _conn = _connFactory.CreateDbConnection(DatabaseConnectionName.Cnn1);
}
public async Task<QueryResult<IBaseReportModel>> Handle(...)
{
 ...
   var query = await _conn.QueryMultipleAsync("Query content here"); // <--- I think the issue comes from here
 ...
}
```

I did think that the way to use is incorrect, need to wrap the call `_conn.QueryMultipleAsync` in `using` statement at least to make sure the connection is closed & disposed then return the connection pool. Because DI container just manages the life cycle of `DapperDbConnectionFactory` only instead of `IDbConnection`

As a result, sometimes I got this error:

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): The connection pool has been
> exhausted, either raise MaxPoolSize (currently 100) or Timeout
> (currently 15 seconds)

I have to restart the app then it turns to normal. So I'm not sure whether the issue is *max connection pool* or *Timeout* due to network. It should be able to check the number of connections in the pool compared to the max connection pool at that time. I'm assuming that.

### Fixing the code

I have 2 ideas:

1. Wrap the call `_conn.QueryMultipleAsync` in `using` statement. But this way I have to change too much code everywhere calling `_conn`.
2. Change the way to DI (The idea comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core)). More details are below.

**Step 1**. `Startup.cs --> ConfigureServices()`

```
services.AddTransient<ServiceResolver>(serviceProvider => cnn_Name =>
{
    switch (cnn_Name)
    {
        case "Cnn1":
            return new NpgsqlConnection("Connectionstring 1");
        case "Cnn2":
            return new NpgsqlConnection("Connectionstring 2");
        default:
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }
});

public delegate IDbConnection ServiceResolver(string connectionstring);
```

**Step 2**: the way I use it:

```
private readonly IDbConnection _conn;

public ConstructorMedthod(ServiceResolver serviceAccessor)
{
   _conn = serviceAccessor(DbConnectionKey.Cnn1);
}

public async Task<QueryResult<IBaseReportModel>> Handle(...)
{
 ...
   var query = await _conn.QueryMultipleAsync("Query content here"); 
   // Now I suppose the _conn will be closed & disposed by DI container.
 ...
}
```

### Questions

1. What is the right way to register DI `NpgsqlConnection` of `postgreSQL` with multiple connection strings in ASP.NET Core 3.1?
2. How can I verify that connection string is returned the connection pool, something like being `Query on PostgreSQL` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435839/how-to-list-active-connections-on-postgresql) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267715/right-query-to-get-the-current-number-of-connections-in-a-postgresql-db) ?

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

3. How to increase the `max connection pool` to greater than 100. Whether it's the best practice? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778015/how-to-increase-the-max-connections-in-postgres) post said that

> Just increasing `max_connections` is bad idea. You need to increase
> `shared_buffers` and `kernel.shmmax` as well.

But actually, I'm using RDS PostgreSQL of AWS. So I'm thinking config `appsettings` like this.

> UserID=root;Password=myPassword;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;Pooling=true;Minimum
> Pool Size=0;`Maximum Pool Size=200;`

Furthermore, As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272459/postgres-npgsql-connection-pooling) post said that

> `Npgsql connection pooling is implemented inside your application process - it has nothing to do with PostgreSQL`, which is completely
> unaware of it.

So I'm very confusing the max connection pool in between the `PostgreSQL` (Question #2) with `Appsettings` (Question #3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, The [author of the current state solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403685/9071943) said that

> **I am not sure if I am using the best practices correctly or not**, but I
> am doing it this way, in order to handle multiple connection strings.

After reading the comment very in detail, I recognized that **You must use `using` statement** like this.

```
public async Task<QueryResult<IBaseReportModel>> Handle(...)
{
 ...
     using(var conn = _connFactory.CreateDbConnection(DatabaseConnectionName.Cnn1))
     {
       var response = await conn.QueryMultipleAsync("Query content here");
     }
 ...
}
```

Otherwise, you will get this error

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): The connection pool has been
> exhausted, either raise MaxPoolSize (currently 100) or Timeout
> (currently 15 seconds)

or

> "53300: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication
> superuser connections"

The highlighted comment is below. Hopefully, It would help you all to avoid hidden mistakes.

[image]

**Updated - 2022-05-13**

From [@Shay Rojansky's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272459/postgres-npgsql-connection-pooling) answer, we already have clarified the [confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272459/postgres-npgsql-connection-pooling#comment127407163_44272654) - *Question #3* between `Appsetings -> Maximum Pool Size=200;` and `PostgreSQL --> SHOW max_connections;`

[image]